# Linphone Turn Server Configuration

Tags: linphone, turn

I am using Linphone using my custom turn server.
Turn server supports both UDP, TLS protocol.
*"turn:turnserver2.example.com:19950?transport=udp",

"turns:turnserver2-dev.example.com:443?transport=tls"*
If Linphone Stun Server Configuration is turnserver2.example.com:19950, Linphone is working but, If I set to turnserver2-dev.example.com:443, not working.
How can I fix it?

Comment: I am facing issue with my custom turn sever using linphone. Here is client logs 

ortp-error-RtpSession error sending [rtp] packet  to turnservierip:49172: Invalid argument [22]

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I am facing exactly same error with Turn relay, I have posted here https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone/issues/531